# Is $W^3(t)$ a martingale if $W(t)$ is a Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Is $W^3(t)$ a martingale if $W(t)$ is a Brownian motion? The answer seems like no to me. Using Ito's lemma I can write
$$W^3(t)=\frac{3}{2}W^2(t)+\int_0^t3W(u)dW(u)$$
The second piece on the LHS is an Ito integral and thus a martingale. However the first piece on the LHS in not a martingale and thus $W^3(t)$ is not a martingale. Can someone confirm or refute my argument (or perhaps make an argument of their own)?

Comment: Since you are still on the site... let me mention that I have no idea how you reached this formula using Itô formula and that I sincerely hope you reread carefully the statement of Itô's formula since you asked this.

Comment: @Did What is your suggestion to see that $W^3(t)$ is no martingale?

Comment: @user893458 Itô, as in an answer below.

Answer (score 6):

You can in fact show that, for any $n>1$, $W(t)^n$ is not a (local) martingale: by applying Ito's lemma, you get:

$dW(t)^n = 0.5n(n-1)W(t)^{n-2}dt + nW(t)^{n-1}dW(t)$

$W(t)^n$ is a (local) martingale iff: $n=1$. Thus, for any $n>1$, $W(t)^n$ is not a (local) martingale.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be the first time that $W_t$ exits the interval $(-1,2)$, which is a stopping time for $W_t$.  We have $T < \infty$ a.s., and by the optional stopping theorem, $E[W_T] =0$.  Thus $P(W_T = -1) = 2/3$ and $P(W_T = 2) = 1/3$.

Now $T$ is also a stopping time for $W_t^3$; it is the first exit time from $(-1,8)$.  Then $E[W_T^3] = \frac{2}{3} (-1)^3 + \frac{1}{3} 2^3 = 2 \ne 0 = E[W_0^3]$.  If $W_t^3$ were a martingale this would contradict the optional stopping theorem.